# Batch file reading dynamic values from properties file and inject values to those values from outside the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, properties, inject

I am trying to inject values to a dynamic values I received from outside a batch script.
To be more clear here is an example:

I have a property file named prop.properties that contain 2 values:

prop.properties

```
path1=%value1%/...
path2=%value1%/...
```

in addition I have a batch myFile.bat file that read the property file.

myFile.bat

```
echo off
set value1=%1
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (prop.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="path1" set val1=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="path2" set val2=%%B 
)

echo %var1%
echo %var2%
```

so after running myFile.bat C:

I will get in the output:
C:/...
c:/...

or if I run:
myFile.bat D:
I will get:
D:/...
D:/...

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you just want parameters. `%1` would be the first one, `%2` the second one etc. So when you call your batch file with `myFile.bat D:`, then from inside the batch file you can access the parameter `C:` with `%1` like `echo %1` or `set "var=%1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do then use delayed variable expansion:

Change percent to exclamation point in prop.proerties

```
path1=!value1!/...
path2=!value1!/...
```

then:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set value1=%1

For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (prop.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="path1" set var1=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="path2" set var2=%%B 
)

echo %var1%
echo %var2%
```

Though there are so many other things/questions.
Here's one idea:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set value1=%1

For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (prop.properties) DO (
    set var_%%A=%%B
)

echo %var_path1%
echo %var_path2%

set var_
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set var_') do echo %%a
```

Though I don't know why you don't just:

```
prop.properties
path1=/...
path2=/...


@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (prop.properties) DO echo %value1%%%A
```